# Qt installed on Debian Stretch

Tags: qt, debian, stretch

I am trying to install Qt Creator on my Debian stretch computer and I am not able to get it to run. The first window opens but seem to be frozen. Clicking on examples, after a some time an error message appears.

```
   Cannot create file  /home/gary/.config/QtProject/qtcreator/device.xml Unknown error
```

Clicking on OK produces a number of simular messages. Then the window closes.

I set the permissions to xrw for all for the .config directory .no help. I then created the QtProject directory and qtcreator directory  with the permissions set to xrw for all. Qt put a couple of files into th QtProject directory but  produced the same error messages.

I installed  Qt using the qt-unified-linux-x64-3.0.4-online.run installation tool from the Qt web site. I have tried to installing using the Synaptic tool but ran into other problems. Qt could not find file. I did not know what packages need to be selected. So that is when I tried the Qt installer.

I have checking this form and others, but have not found anything that worked or any thing less then a year old.

Any and all suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Gary

Comment: Check the owner of the directory `/home/gary/.config/QtProject`

Comment: Thanks Mohammad. Yes I tried that before. I do not get the normal message, "cannot write file, permission denied" or something to that effect. The error message said “unknown error”. Not much help. I think I am going to give up on the Qt installer from the Qt web site and go back to the synaptic installer that came with the Debian distribution. The problem is picking the right files to install. There are literally hundreds.

Thanks again,
Gary
WB4CLP